Swift CoreData computed stored property
I have a model with two attributes: price and quantity.
I have a computed property totalPrice defined as:
@objc(BasketItem)
class BasketItem: NSManagedObject {
    var totalPrice: Double {
        price * quantity
    }
}

I need to sort on that computed property and obviously it doesn't work with Core Data.
So, I'd like to persist this totalPrice instead as a regular property.
But I would need to keep it in sync with the two others at all time. Meaning that if I update price or quantity, it automatically update my totalPrice.
In my model, I'm using the Codegen Category/Extension.
What would be the proper way to keep my totalPrice synchronized?
Can we use something like didSet on price and quantity? If so, how could I override or trigger it from my subclass BasketItem?
Thanks!

Perhaps willSave() could work

I think willSave() would only trigger when the model is actually saved to the database, no? I need it to be updated as soon as one of the other two value is updated.

Yes only when saving, that's why I wrote "perhaps" :). maybe something like this question
